# Protecting connection strings during dev

Tags: .net, encryption, connection-string, rsa, dpapi

We need to protect connection strings **during development**.  On servers we use DPAPI which works fine.  DPAPI is not an option during dev since the connection strings will need to be decrypted on many machines.

Some of the user names/password used for dev are rather sensitive and we don't want them floating around.  It's fine for all the devs to be able to decrypt them, just want to ensure that if someone else gets their hands on the dev config files that person can't decrypt the connection strings.  Using all service accounts instead of sensitive username/password is not an option due to external constraints.

My first inclination is to use the RSA provider for encrypting and installing the cert on the dev machines.

So my questions are;

1) How do you approach this issue?

2) If you take the RSA approach is there more up-to-date documentation than [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx)

Thanks

Comment: Does the database support integrated security (SSPI)? Then you don't need passwords in the connection string.

Comment: @Richard - integrated security is not an option for the systems we are targeting.

Comment: well, it should if the above is the scenario, I don't like this question :(. Also I hope all of this is with dev servers involved, and we are not talking about production. These particular username/pwds for devs shouldn't be used for something else.

Comment: @eglasius  Yes we are talking about dev.  Please don't assume that integrated security is an option.  We are not talking about SQL Server and the system we are connecting to is third party, hence the authentication method is out of our control.

Comment: +1 I got carried away :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after more research we went with the RSA approach.  Found some more updated documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw.aspx).  If you are going down this road make sure you read everything RSA related in that link.  Below are the steps we used if anyone is interested...

--FIRST TIME ONLY

-create the key container, making it exportable

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "MyKeys" -exp
```

-add this section to config file

```
<configProtectedData>
  <providers>
    <add name="RsaProvider"
         type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0,&#xD;&#xA;                    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,&#xD;&#xA;                    processorArchitecture=MSIL"


         keyContainerName="MyKeys"
         useMachineContainer="true" />
  </providers>
</configProtectedData>
```

-encrypt the connection strings

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\Working\MyApplication" -prov RsaProvider
```

-give out the config file

-to decrypt

```
aspnet_regiis -pdf "connectionStrings" "C:\Working\MyApplication"
```

-export keys (will create keys.xml)

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "MyKeys" -exp
```

--On some other machine

-save keys.xml somewhere

-import the keys. make sure the name (e.g. MyKeys) is the same

> aspnet_regiis -pi "MyKeys" keys.xml

-delete keys.xml!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

-give permissions to the service account if running as part of a webapp

e.g. `aspnet_regiis -pa "PcscDev" "ASPNET"`